# How do I access devise protected methods ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Rails 4.0.2 and Devise 3.2.2 to handle user registration / authentication. I have enabled `:confirmable`

How do I access/call devise protected methods inside my app? 
I'm trying to use the protected `confirmation_period_expired?` method from

http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Confirmable#confirmation_period_expired%3F-instance_method

But I got an `NoMethodError: protected method confirmation_period_expired?` error.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally not a good idea, but if you absolutely have to:

```
@user.send(:confirmation_period_expired?)
```

will do it.

Comment: It is considered an unsafe practice. You are deliberately bypassing security measures set in place by another programmer. Just figured I would tack on a warning if I'm giving advise on how to do something like that. :)

Comment: hi willmanduffy, does this work with rails only? cos I'm trying to access the protected method in lib/tasks and when I run the task, it says `undefined method 'confirmation_period_expired?' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_User:0x000001049b1ce8>`

Comment: You're trying to call a user method on an ActiveRecord relation, not the user object. Try: relation.first.send(:method_name)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Im trying to call all the Users with condition `confirmation_period_expired? = true `, i tried `users = User.all.send(:confirmation_period_expired?) (:conditions => 'confirmation_period_expired? is true')` but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Besides `send` you could define a public method on `User`. This method can call the protected method on itself.

```ruby
class User
  def is_confirmation_period_expired?
    self.confirmation_period_expired? # self is optional
  end
end
```

Can you can call the method on user without an error: `@user.is_confirmation_period_expired?`